# Java create a class to print ArrayList to file

Tags: java, class, file-io, printwriter

Here is the code I have.

This is my PrintToFile class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PrintToFile{
        File f;
        FileWriter fw;
        PrintWriter pw;

    public void PrintToFile()throws Exception{//remove void from constructor
      File f = new File ("Output.txt");//dont reinitialize 
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);//dont reinitialize 
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);//dont reinitialize 
   }

    public void printExp(ArrayList<Expense> expList){
        for(int i = 0; i < expList.size(); i++){
         pw.println("---------------------------------------");//exception here
         pw.println(expList.get(i));
      }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

in my main class here is my call to print my ArrayList

```
    PrintToFile printer = new PrintToFile();
    printer.printExp(expList);
```

I have defined expList as an ArrayList of objects

The exception I get is a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

occuring where marked.  My question is what is causing this exception?  Thanks

Comment: thanks everyone! not sure about the downvote?? but thanks for all the answers it now works perfectly

Comment: +1 Maybe someone is whining about your indenting style ;)

Comment: As you probably now realize, whenever you "declare" a variable (put the datatype - e.g. File - in front of a variable) it creates a new  variable. So, you had 2 variables named "f" of type File. 

When a variable is declared, it is restricted to it the scope within it's enclosing curly braces. When the brackets are exited, the variable goes out of scope. When there is a conflict of variable name, the smallest scope wins. Therefore your "File f" in PrintToFile() constructor overshadowed the "File f" class-variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating object of `pw` which is class field but you are creating object of `pw` which is local to method `PrintToFile()`. So by default `PrintToFile.pw` is null and you get `NPE`.

Change your method to following or initialize `pw`,`f` and `fw` in constructor(recommended):

```
public void PrintToFile() throws Exception {
      f = new File ("Output.txt");
      fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
      pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
File f = new File ("Output.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
```

Do as following:

```
f = new File ("Output.txt");
fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
```

You are declaring local variables again in constructor. and the instance variables remain initialized by default value (i.e null).

Answer (score 1):

pw is not set as a global variable in your constructor. Fix your constructor as well, it shouldn't be void.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PrintToFile
{
    File f;
    FileWriter fw;
    PrintWriter pw;

    public PrintToFile() throws Exception{
        f = new File ("Output.txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    }

    public void printExp(ArrayList<Expense> expList)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < expList.size(); i++)
        {
            pw.println("---------------------------------------");//exception here
            pw.println(expList.get(i));
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove void (constructor don't have void or any return type).
And declarete variable only once.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PrintToFile
{
    File f;
    FileWriter fw;
    PrintWriter pw;

    public PrintToFile() throws Exception
    {
        f = new File ("Output.txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    }

    public void printExp(ArrayList<Expense> expList)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < expList.size(); i++)
        {
            pw.println("---------------------------------------");
            pw.println(expList.get(i));
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```